# Batch script to remove parts of a filename within variable characters

Tags: bash, shell, sed, rename, mv

Help please!

I have a set of 60 files named in the following format:

- XXXXX_L2_R1_001_XneCgnfdkjTTTnm.fastq.gz
- XXXXX_L2_R2_001_GmnbkjZZnvhkfPn.fastq.gz

and I would like to remove the "_L2" part and everything else after the third underscore, in order to have something like:

- XXXXX_R1.fastq.gz
- XXXXX_R2.fastq.gz

The number "XXXXX" varies between the files, and for each number there is always a R1 file and a R2 file.

Maybe a rename or a sed command can help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post what you have tried till now and what didn't work. It sounds like you want us to do your work for you

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Which operating system? Which shell? What does [tag:batchfile] have to do with your question?

Comment: I apologize if I came across that way. In fact, I searched for this command for almost two days. I have tried to use rename, sed, mv commands that I found during my search trough stackoverflow, stackexchange, askubuntu, and unix foruns. I used commands like `rename 's/\_L2/\//g' *_L2` or `for i in *; do mv $i `echo $i | cut -d"_" -f1'`, but I was stuck on only deleting everything after a certain underscore and that was not the output I wanted.

Comment: Operating system is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and I'm using bash. I'm new to this thing, so I believe there was some confusion regarding batch-file, as well as between batch and bash. It's all good now. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `rename` utility you can do this:

```
rename -n 's/^([^_]+)_L2(_[^_]+)[^.]+(\..+)$/$1$2$3/' *.gz
```

Once satisfied with dry run remove `-n` option and rerun.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava! it worked out perfectly.